# Is it possible to write C# code in salesforce ?

Tags: salesforce

I am new with the salesforce, I am curious that can we choose C# or any other programming language to customized salesforce application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Salesforce platform provide their own language - Apex (pretty similar to Java) and you need to use it for implementation of backend logic. On frontend you can use Visualforce tags or JavaScript (or all other that can be compiled to JS).

Comment: Got it ! Thank you!